# Android/Eclipse: When should I write "import com.mydevname.mypackagename.R" in my java classes headings?

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I have many issues with the "R.something" items in my project. I have often the "xx cannot be resolved" error. I noticed that to remove this error, I have to write or remove "import com.mydevname.mypackagename.R" in my java classes headings...but I absolutely don't understand the logic !

Somebody knows how to do the right choice ??

Thanks a lot !

Comment: the r tag is not for this purpose, its for the statistical analysis language R.

Answer (score 2):

The `R.class` is generated by the Android framework when you compile and is basicly a list of resources.

If in your class you reference something like `R.id.mySomething` or `R.strings.myString` you will need a to import your `R.class` just like you need to import any other class which you utilize inside your own class (If you use a `List` you have to import `java.util.List`).

If you don't reference your project specific `R.class` your compiler will most probably think that you are referencing the `android.R` file which holds standard android things, and not the layouts/strings/resources you have created for your project.

Comment: Thanks KasperMoerch. But in the classes where I should do the import, I have got the following error in front of the import: "the import cannot be resolved". Do you know what is the issue ? Note that my gen folder is empty...

Comment: There might be some problems compiling then. There should be a `R.java` file in your gen folder.

Answer (score 0):

One of your XML files probably has an error. Eclipse doesnt want to create the R.java 
so everything goes missing!

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse using the ADT your `[packagename]/R.java` file will be generated automatically to contain a link to all of your resources by ID.

New ID's are added to your `R.java` file when you build your project. In Eclipse you can simply press "Ctrl+B" to manually start a build process. Since Eclipse isn't fool proof, you may have to do a "Clean & Build" from the Project menu.

When inside your java file and you're coding and referencing ID's you've specified in XML, you can simply write `R.` and then do two things:

- Either press "Ctrl+Shift+O", this will automatically organise (and add) any imports needed as best it can.
- Press "Ctrl+Space" to give you a suggested options. When one of these is selected the import statement will be generated automatically.

When it has a problem with importing a resource it will give you options. When referencing R it will ask you for `[packagename].R` which is your R for ID's you've defined or "`android.R`" which are predefined ID's shipped with the Android API.

Most of the time you will be using your own R file in the import and you may manually select useful properties from the API by fully qualifying `Android.R` (`Android.R.color.transparent` for instance).

Hope this helps.